# Is there a way for symlinks to mimic a whole path?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, links

I have a config file I don't want changed with Many relative paths.
example : data/shared/images and data/shared/documents.
I want these paths to link to /media/images and /media/documents etc ..
I tried :

```
ln -s /media/documents data/shared/documents
```

but I get `"failed to create symbolic link 'data/shared/documents' no such file of directory`.. I understand that symbolic links don't do that.
So my question: is there a way to solve this problem without having to create data/shared folders and then making a "documents" symlink to /media/documents/ etc ..? as some of these have a lot of nested folders I would have to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `data/shared/` folder (`mkdir -p data/shared`). Your link is going to be stored in that folder.

Be sure to use `ln -s` the right way : `ln -s /point/to/this/dir /sym/link/location/symlink_name`. The way you use it - as currently described - it is going to link you to the content of `/media/documents`, and not `/media/images/`.

If your issue persists, try some of the following :

- use the complete path `/path/to/data/shared/images`
- Does `/media/documents` exist before you create the symlink?

EDIT
If you want to to link to a bunch of folders at the same time (for example `data/X` to /media/documents/X`, then you should consider to create the pointer`data/shared`towards`/media/documents`. This way you don't have to create links to a lot of folders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes the folder exists. 
So from what i understand there is no way for a symlink to act as a whole path ... if i want a ./really/long/path/symlink and a ./other/really/long/path/symlink2 etc .. parent folders have to exist

Comment: yes. In order for your symlink to be found, the OS has to go through the folders in its path